# Workday Extend format option for cellTemplate type="date"

Tags: workday-api

I am implementing a grid in a Workday Extend worklet.

The code for the date column looks like this:

```
        {
          "type": "column",
          "columnId": "c3",
          "label": "Start Date",
          "sortableAndFilterable": "true",
          "cellTemplate": {
            "type": "date",
            "value": "<% grdRow.startDate %>"
          }
        },
```

It was "type":"text".
Now I would like to make it "type":"date" The grdRow.startDate is a date type.

I also want to format the date in a format of "DD-MMM-YYYY".
I cannot find something in the Workday documentation about an option to format a date column.

Do I really need to format it my self in the underlying report and view as text?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is a view page, you can use the "dateDisplayPattern" attribute on the "date" widget.

Note: An edit page uses the preferred display language of the signed-in user to determine the display format of the date widget. An edit page ignores the dateDisplayPattern attribute.